# Kafka Headers as List in batch mode

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I am trying to access some headers whilst consuming messages in batch mode.
If I setup the listener to handle `Message<?>` I can manually extract the headers

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "${kafka.topic}")
public void receive (List<Message<?> data, Acknowledgment ack) throws SQLException {
  for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); ++) {
    Object message = data.get(i).getPayload();
    MessageHeaders mh = data.get(i).getHeaders();
    Object value = mh.get("test");
```

I would like to have some of this done for me but when I try

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "${kafka.topic}")
public voic receive (List<string> data,
  @Header (KafkaHeaders.OFFSET) List<Integer> offsets,
  @Header ("test") List<String> testHeaders,
  Acknowledgment ack) throws SQLException {
```

I get `MessageHandlingException: Missing header 'test' for method parameter type [interface.java.util.list]`
This method however works fine for the offset header.

Is this because there is inbuilt code to handle the standard headers and this approach cannot be used for custom ones or have I missed something that would make this approach work?

Comment: Did you try with fresh topic? Maybe you published earlier messages without "test" header and your consumer's `spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset` set to `earliest` ?

Comment: I didn't however I did dump the data using the `Message<?>` code and every record had the header set.

Comment: BTW, keep in mind that you are trying to read list of string from header field, but this is not the issue.  Could you also share your producer ?

Comment: And there is the issue...  I don't have access to the producer.  To dump the data I inserted it into a database using the first bit of code and the header converted to a string fine.   I did try using different types in the list (`Byte[]`, `Object`, `?`) but still got the same issue.

Comment: Did you actually successfully print out the `value` that you obtained from `mh.get("test")`. I'm asking this because It might return null.

Comment: Yes this output fine to the database (and would have been through a JDBC prepared statement and setString).    As above every single value had this header set

Comment: This might be related to you spring boot version. What is your spring boot version and spring-kafka version?

Comment: Headers not known by the framework are collected into a list of maps. See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the framework only maps the headers it knows about; it puts all other mapped headers into

```java
/**
 * The header for a list of Maps of converted native Kafka headers. Used for batch
 * listeners; the map at a particular list position corresponds to the data in the
 * payload list position.
 */
public static final String BATCH_CONVERTED_HEADERS = PREFIX + "batchConvertedHeaders";
```

If you want a discrete mapping for that header, you would need to create a custom `BatchMessageConverter` - probably a subclass of `BatchMessagingMessageConverter`.

Probably the easiest would be to override [this method](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/blob/ad6e2a148d082c601081df5dfea8d3fcc906a3e3/spring-kafka/src/main/java/org/springframework/kafka/support/converter/BatchMessagingMessageConverter.java#L126-L181), call `super.toMessage()` then add your headers.

```java
return MessageBuilder.fromMessage(super.toMessage(...))
    .setHeader("test", ...)
    .build();
```

If you are using Spring Boot, just add the converter as a bean and boot will wire it in.

Otherwise add the converter to the container factory.

**EDIT**

If the message converter has no header mapper; all headers are put in the header `KafkaHeaders.NATIVE_HEADERS` which is a `List<Headers>`.